# prove the identity for a differentiable function

Tags: analysis, differential

Let $f$ be a smooth real function and $f(0)=0, f (1)=1$, prove that exists various $x_1$, $x_2$ $ \in [0;1] $ such that $$\frac{1}{f'(x_1)}+\frac{1}{f'(x_2)}=2$$
I tried to use the mean value theorem for different intervals, but it didn't help me.
Also I can't understand the behavior of this function.
Thank you for help!